# Should I wrap jquery ajax inside Promise or return jquery ajax directly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I am using jquery version 3.5.1 which supports then and catch for ajax requests.

What is recommended practice between below two codes?

First wraps ajax call in Promise, and second returns ajax call directly.

**First**

```
function first() {  
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    $.ajax({
            url: '...',
            method: 'get',          
            success: function(response){
                resolve(response.title + ' first');
            },
            error: function(error){
                reject();
            }
        });
  });
}

first().then(function(data){
    console.log(data);
  });
```

OR

**Second**

```
function second() {  
    return $.ajax({
              url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',
                method: 'get'            
              })
                .then(function(response){           
                  return response.title + ' second';
                })
  }

second().then(function(data){
    console.log(data);
  });
```

I somewhere read that wrapping ajax call inside Promise is anti-pattern.
Which code should I use?

I created js fiddle for this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/ajinkya1221/7zu0n1gb/23/)

Comment: `$.ajax` should return a Promise - or close enough - depends on jQuery version - you could even `return Promise.resolve($.ajax(....))` that way you get a native Promise (not that that should matter, a thenable is a thenable)

Comment: thank you !. so that means return $.ajax() is recommended and wrapping $.ajax inside new Promise is anti-pattern.

Comment: exactly - unless the jquery version is very old, then I'd recommend the "anti-pattern" - but nobody should be using jquery that is that old